# Static linking of Fortran program with some C routines

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, fortran

I have a Fortran program with two small C routines for I/O. I use GCC to compile and link this on Windows, Linux and MacOS (well, on Catalina I need to use Mac's own C compiler) and it works.

Now I wanted to link this program using `-static` to run the program on a computer which does not have the Fortran libraries. This worked on Windows but on Linux the linker failed stating `-lm -lc missing`.  On MacOS it failed complained `-lcro0.o missing`.

The whole program is available at opencalphad repository at github including a Makefile, the only thing needed to modify is to add "-static" in the line for linking.  Without -static it works.

Any suggestion what can be done?

Comment: I guess showing your full compiler/linker command lines would help.

Comment: If it helps the line to link all together on Windows is   gfortran -o oc5A -static pmain1.F90 pmon6.o smp2.o ftinyopen.o tinyopen.o tinyfiledialogs.o liboceq.a -lcomdlg32 -lole32

Comment: If your linux distro follows the usual practice of the last 8 years, it doesn't include the static libraries you are requesting.  For friendly distros, you should find them downloadable, probably in both source and objects.  For commercial ones, it could be a prohibitive additional fee.

Comment: To add to @tiim18's comment, -static tells gfortran to link in the files libm.a and libc.a.  Your system seems to lack those libraries.  On MacOS, I suspect that libcro0.o is the start up code that should get linked in.  You don't have those either.

Comment: I have now seen another comment about using -static and I understand it is not generally available on Linux, one reason being it would make it too easy to provide software to those who has not paid for the compiler.

Comment: @BoSundman, gfortran is a part of GCC.  One can get it for free (in both senses of the word).

Comment: with gfortran on linux, there is the option "-static-libgfortran" that only links statically the libgfortran library, while the rest is dynamically linked. This may achieve what you want.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl Thanks -static-libgfortran worked.  I compile and link on CentOS but I hope that OC will work on most Linux versions.

Comment: If you aim for broad linux compatibility you should look at the manylinux python wheel system. Its purpose is to generate maximally compatible binary libraries for pyhton but it can help for your problem too.